# Java (Button+Graphics)

Tags: java

I just started to work with Java.
I have no problems with creating window,button and any graphics.
But, i cant make window with many buttons, graphics and text boxes.
When i add buttons to my window i cant see graphics.
How can i do it?

code:

```
package today;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class mybuttonapp extends JFrame
{



    private mybuttonapp()
    {
     }



    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //new mybuttonapp().setVisible(true);

        //--

        JFrame f=new JFrame("Button Example"); 
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(900, 600);
        //f.setLayout(null);  
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        p1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (100,100));
        p1.setVisible(true);
        f.add(p1);


        My2d paint1 = new My2d();



        JButton b1=new JButton("Click Here");  
        b1.setBounds(10,10,100,50);


        p1.add(b1);  
        p1.add(paint1);  
        }

code 2:

package today;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class My2d extends JComponent

{
       public void paint (Graphics g)
        {

           Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

           Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(300,300,50,50);
            g2.fill(circle);

          }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to look at are layouts in swing. If I get what you ask and what you're doing you are overwriting whatever you set first.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html
This link provides explanations to all of the swing layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check how LayoutManagers work in Java. They help you to put the elements in the right place within your container (JFrame/JPanel). 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html

Normally I work with a combination of `BorderLayout` and `GridBagLayout`, since it is quite flexible - but many users feel `GridBagLayout` is too complicated, especially for beginners.